# Python threads leak memory

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-leaks

I have a test script that starts multiple threads, joins them and checks resident memory used by the process:

```
from threading import Thread
import resource


def resident_memory() -> int:
    return resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss


def work():
    a = 'Hello world'
    a += '!!!'


def run_threads(count: int) -> None:
    for _ in range(count):
        t = Thread(target=work)
        t.start()
        t.join()


def run_workers(count: int) -> None:
    for _ in range(count):
        work()


while True:
    print('Mem usage:', resident_memory())
    run_threads(10000)
    #run_workers(10000)
```

It seems like resident memory is constantly growing even though I join the threads.
If I run the `work()` function in the main thread, no memory leak is detected.
I'm testing with python 3.5.
Is this a known problem?